# PostgreSQL DECLARE a text variable and use it into INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, declare

I'm trying to declare a text variable and insert it into my `movie` table.

This is what I'm doing:

```
DECLARE movie_plot TEXT;
movie_plot := '{test}';

INSERT INTO movie(plot) VALUES (movie_plot);
```

It gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TEXT"
LINE 1: DECLARE movie_plot TEXT;
                           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 20
```

I already checked some solved questions similar to mine and this sintax seems correct. I saw that I could use the `WITH` to solve the problem, but i would like to use the `DECLARE`.

Comment: `DECLARE` (and thus variables) can only be used inside PL/pgSQL code not in SQL

Comment: "I already checked some solved questions similar to mine and this sintax seems correct." -- Not in SQL in Postgres, as @a_horse_with_no_name already commented. Maybe the other questions targeted another DBMS than Postgres. (SQL Server?). Maybe you want to explain the *underlying* problem, you try to solve with your approach, to get help on *that*.

Comment: But I am using Postgres, I'm writing my SQL on PgAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use [`current_setting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-admin.html):

```
SET my_vars.movie_plot = 'test';
INSERT INTO movie(plot) VALUES (current_setting('my_vars.movie_plot'));
```